# RethinkDB shards & replicas vs MongoDB shards & replicas sets

Tags: rethinkdb

In MongoDB,  when you want to let say have a 3 shards with replica-sets, you end up needing, for production use, a minumum of 7 servers (2 per shard for high-availability + 1 arbitrer at least).

In RethinkDB, I can't find some equivalent or good sugestions, in terms of cluster architecture & design.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need at least 3 servers for automatic failover to work.  You generally want one shard per server.  I'd recommend starting with that unless you're doing out of date reads or the write load on your servers is too high, in which case I'd switch to having one shard or replica per server (so number of servers = number of shards * replication setting).

RethinkDB doesn't have separate arbiters, so those don't need to enter into your calculation.